MultiModal Cross attention
I am dealing with two embeddings, text and image both are last_hidden_state of transfomer models (bert and vit), so the shapes are (batch, seq, emd_dim). I want to feed text information to image using a cross attention mechanism and I was wondering whether this line of code will give me what I need:
cross_attention = nn.MultiheadAttention(embed_dim=768, num_heads=12, dropout=0.1)
attn_output, attn_output_weights = cross_attention(text_last, img_last, img_last)

I tried the provided code but I am not sure whether it is the right approach

Attention accepts arguments: Q,K,V in this order. So you try to search (query) text embedding in image embedding keys? If image and text embeddings are not mapped to the same space, then it would be wrong. If they are - sounds OK, but the whole architecture would matter whether it's correct or not
